# Understanding defn. of compound poisson processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am reading about what seems to be called compound Poisson distributions in Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability, edition 3, in chapter 7. He has the following lemma:

**Let $\xi$ be a random vector in $R^d$, fix a bounded measure $\nu \ne 0$ on $R^d - {0}$, and let $c = ||\nu||, \nu' = \nu/c$. Then, the following are equivalent**:

**(i) $\xi =_d X_{\kappa}$, for random walk $X = (X_n)$ in $R^d$ based on $\nu'$, where $\kappa$ is independent of $X$ and Poisson distributed with mean $c$**.

**(ii) $\xi =_{d} \int x \eta (dx)$, for Poisson process $\eta$ on $R^d - {0}$ with $E(\eta) = \nu$.**

Specifically, I thought that, in the integral, $x \in R^d - {0}$ since $\eta$ is a Poisson process on $R^d - {0}$, but then I don't see how the integral itself makes sense. So:

1. How do we interpret the integral above?
2. Why should this be the same process as described in (i)?
3. Does this correspond to the definition of [compound Poisson processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process) on Wikipedia? I don't think so, because that is explicitly stated as a continuous time process, whereas here we have a fixed random variable.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your questions in order:

1. The integral is easier to interpret than you think. Saying that $\eta$ is a Poisson process on $R^d - 0$ only means that there is no point in 0. But in the same sense, we can interpret it as a Poisson process on $R^d$ (without point in 0)! Also, note that $x$ is 0 in 0 anyway, so that it doesn't even matter whether there is a point in 0 or not.
2. Note that (as long as $\nu$ is bounded), saying that $\eta$ is a Poisson process on $R^d$ with measure $\nu$ is the same as taking a Poisson number with mean $\Vert \nu\Vert$ of points, distributed independently with distribution $\nu'$. If we denote this Poisson number by $\kappa$ and enumerate the points $x_i$ from $1$ to $\kappa$ (in some arbitrary order), we get
   $$
   \int x\;\eta(\mathrm d x) = \sum_{x\in \eta} x = \sum_{i=1}^\kappa x_i
   $$
   which is exactly a RW based on $\nu'$.
3. The compound Poisson process described in the Wikipedia article can be viewed as a special case by viewing time as another space dimension. Indeed, taking the notation from there, let $\nu'$ be the distribution of the independent $D_i$ and consider $\nu(\mathrm d t, \mathrm d x) := 1_{[0,t]}\mathrm d t\otimes \nu'$ on $R^2$; the first dimension being time. Then, $\Vert \nu\Vert = t$ and we obtain the compound Poisson process.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Your equations in (2) don't seem to be rendered. Also, my contention in (1) isn't the exclusion of $0$: rather, the integral $\int_{R^d} x \eta (dx)$ is over $R^d$: in particular, our integrand is $x \in R^d$ rather than a real-valued function $f(x):R^d \rightarrow R$, and I'm unable to make sense of this. I think I'm misinterpreting how the Poisson process is defined?

Comment: ah I see. It is the same as in the integral $\int_0^1 x\;\mathrm d x$. What you are integrating is the identity map $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: And a Poisson (point) process is simply a **random** (multi)set of points. This can be interpreted as a **random** counting measures, i.e. a **random** measure that consists only of a sum of Dirac measures. The fact that it is a **random** measure can be hard to parse at the beginning... This also justifies my notation: on the lefthand side, we have the integral that interprets $\eta$ as a measure (as a sum of Diracs) and the middle sum interprets $\eta$ as the corresponding multiset of points.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for clarifying! You have really helped @Mushu Nrek